# URLs Embedded in Lotus Notes Emails Cause Double Click

Tags: url, hyperlink, lotus

I'm including an http:// hyperlink to a url in emails I send to certain clients.

When they click on this it launches a URL that then instigates some logic on our server side to deal with the request from the email client.

The problem I have is with Lotus Notes clients.  It works fine on Outlook, Mac, Gmail, iOS etc etc.  However, if somoene using Lotus Notes clicks on the hyperlink, I always get two requests, as if they'd double clicked.

If it helps, the users I'm testing with are behind a corporate firewall (not my company's firewall).

Any ideas as this is becoming really frustrating...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to make the mail? Lotus Notes translates the emails it recieves to its own rich text format. That does not always translate well with the originaly created email.

Apart from that, can you see any difference between the link called from Lotus Notes compared to the other email clients? In a log or something? Do you actually see 2 clicks coming in. Or is you server performing some kind of transformation or redirect?